# constructing isomorphism of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

How is one to define an isomorphism between $End(E)$ and $E\otimes  E^*$ for a vector space $E$, it seems that $E\otimes E$ is also isomorphic to the former but perhaps it is not canonical? How can you prove the isomorphism is canonical?

Comment: Is your vector space finite dimensional? How do you define "canonical"?

Comment: I guess that $End(E)$ and $E\otimes E^*$ are not isomorphic if $E$ is not finite dimensional. Elements in $E\otimes E^*$ gives those linear mappings which have finite dimensional range.

Comment: It is only valid for finite dimensional vector spaces

Comment: @779052 if $E$ is finite-dimensional, then consider the mapping $E\otimes E^* \to \operatorname{End}(E)$ sending $w\otimes f$ to the endomorphism $v\mapsto f(v)w$.